# Missing typings when using window.require with Electron and TypeScript with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron, babeljs, create-react-app

I have an Electron app that uses `create-react-app` with the TypeScript configuration (which uses Babel to compile the TypeScript code to JavaScript).

I've followed the advice to use `window.require` in this case when importing modules like `electron-store` which access the filesystem, to avoid collision with Babel's `require` (which would error out with e.g. `fs.whatever not found`).

My issue is that these modules come in typed as `any`, even when typing information is available. How do I clue TypeScript into the typing information for modules imported with `window.require`?

To make it specific, here's an example:

```
const Store = window.require('electron-store');

type StoreType = {
  'root-path': string;
};

// fails with "Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments."
export const store = new Store<StoreType>();
```

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done generically, that is to say for arbitrary module specifiers, but I suspect only a few modules will be loaded this way. Given that, your best bet is to write something like

```
 // augmentations.d.ts or whatever you want to call it.

 import ElectronStore from 'electron-store';

 declare global {
   interface Window {
     require(moduleSpecifier: 'electron-store'): typeof ElectronStore;
     require(moduleSpecifier: 'some-specifier'): SomeType; 
   }
 }
```

Comment: exactly the kind of workaround I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: this is very close, but in `.d.ts` files I don't think `typeof` is valid (it fails with `ElectronStore is not defined` if I use `typeof`) and if I omit `typeof`, I think the namespace is used instead of the class (they are defined with the same name in electron-store source here: https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-store/blob/master/index.d.ts), resulting in "Type 'ElectronStore<any>' has no construct signatures."

Comment: It depends on what `ElectionStore` is declared as. `typeof` is valid in ambient contexts and is required to obtain the type of a class as opposed to the type of its instance. The declarations of the class and the namespace are merged in the standard way

Comment: well, when I import it via window.require I get a class with a constructor, but when I import it in the ambient context I get something else, without a constructor. not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The type will be the same. But you can't call it in an ambient context. If my example is wrong I will fix it but I am not clear on what you are doing